# bidirectional and deterministic binary decrement

Tags: binary, prolog

I am wondering whether its possible to implement in pure Prolog alone a binary decrementer which is bidirectional and deterministic. Example runs include and for mode (-,+):

```
?- dec(X,[0,0,1]).
X = [1,0,1]
?- dec(X,[1,1,1]).
X = [0,0,0,1]
```

And for mode (+,-):

```
?- dec([1,0,1],X).
X = [0,0,1]
?- dec([0,0,0,1],X).
X = [1,1,1]
```

Optionally none of the modes should leave any [choice points](http://www.ai.sri.com/pubs/files/641.pdf). But mandatorily the implementation must be in pure Prolog alone, so no cut, no findall, no var, etc...

I already tried a definition as follows `dec(X,Y) :- binary_plus([1],Y,X).` using the binary adder [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29394110/9904704). But it doesn't pass the last test case, since I get `dec([0,0,0,1],X). X = [1, 1, 1]; X = [1, 1, 1, 0] ; false.`.

Comment: Same recent deleted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55650270/revisions) by [j4n bur53](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502187/j4n-bur53)

Comment: Hint: think of the problem as a [*finite state transducer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_transducer).

Comment: You need to define what you mean by deterministic. It seems you mean: Does not leave a choice point on a specific Prolog system. Which one are you referring to? [A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380105/prolog-binary-addition/29394110#comment97975583_29394110) in the linked post suggests that there are differences between SWI and another system.

Comment: @false I have flagged your comment. You are harrassing me with irrelevant nonsense. This is not the first time. Deterministic is defined as in deterministic relation in mathematics. Choice point (CP) is defined as in the WAM, including optimizations that would omit CP. Concerning CPs the question says only SHOULD, and it doesn't say MUST.

Comment: SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
   may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
   particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
   carefully weighed before choosing a different course. https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt

Answer (score 2):

The following two queries test for determinism. They do not succeed.  Both run infinitely as is ; and fail with a given `N`. To indicate that non-termination is intended, the queries are prefixed with `:/-&`.

```
:/-& length(Bs,N), dec(Bs, Ds1), dif(Ds1, Ds2), dec(Bs, Ds2).

:/-& length(Ds,N), dec(Bs1, Ds), dif(Bs1, Bs2), dec(Bs2, Ds).

dec([1|Bs],[0|Bs]) :-
   nil_or_ends_with_one(Bs).
dec([0|Bs],[1|Ds]) :-
   deci(Bs, Ds).

nil_or_ends_with_one([]).
nil_or_ends_with_one([E|Es]) :-
   ends_with_one(Es, E).

ends_with_one([], 1).
ends_with_one([E|Es], _) :-
   ends_with_one(Es, E).

deci([1],[]).
deci([1|Bs],[0|Bs]) :-
   Bs = [B|_],
   ends_with_one(Bs, B).
deci([0|Bs],[1|Ds]) :-
   deci(Bs, Ds).
```

The solution is still a bit too general, in that it accepts

```
?- dec([1,non_digit,1],[0,non_digit,1]).
```

This can be easily fixed but does not seem to be worth the cost.

Comment: In SWI-Prolog this almost doesn't leave a choice point. Probably because it goes into structured arguments during indexing. The test case, from the four test cases, where I get a choice point is ?- dec([0,0,0,1],X). X = [1, 1, 1] ; false. Can this be improved?

Answer (score 1):

I got a different solution which is not targeted towards a [deep indexing](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=deep-indexing) Prolog, rather a flat indexing Prolog. So far all 4 test cases do not leave any choice point in Jekejeke Prolog which has full flat indexing. :-)

```
% check binary number
num([]).
num([X|Y]) :- dig(X, Y).

dig(1, []).
dig(T, [X|Y]) :- aux(T, X, Y).

aux(0, X, Y) :- dig(X, Y).
aux(1, X, Y) :- dig(X, Y).

% check binary number and its pseudo decrement
dec([X|Y], Z) :- dig(X, Y, Z).

dig(1, [], []).
dig(T, [X|Y], [U|V]) :- aux(T, U, V, X, Y).

aux(0, 1, Z, X, Y) :- dig(X, Y, Z).
aux(1, 0, [X|Y], X, Y) :- dig(X, Y).
```

https://gist.github.com/jburse/649f828c330ff3c770834ee8bca250a8#file-tarai-p

But the drawback of full flat indexing is the additional overhead when coding a predicate, to bring it into flat form. Flat form is also popular as the binary_plus/3 example shows. But the best would possibly be to have both flat and deep, and the later in a way that there exists a

deep dec/2 version which never leaves choice points.